# Server sent events (SSE) - automatic reconnect

Tags: http, go, server-sent-events

I am having trouble understanding how the "automatic reconnect" works for SSE.

I've been reading the documentation of Mozilla and WC3 and several other discussions, but still I am still not sure how it works.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events

I have implemented SSE using gorilla/mux in Golang and it all works. Now to the interesting part, I can break the connection from the server but the connection will magically be restored seconds later. I haven't implemented any functionality for this myself, so I am not sure how this happens?

All major browsers will try to automatically reconnect, however I never manually set any Event ID. Will the the browser reconnect but just not receive any lost data sent during disconnect? (this is what the use of EventID can solve, but I have no interest in it). Ie, can the browser reconnect without the use of EventID? Or could it be something else that makes this "reconnect" possible?

Comment: The client automatically reconnects to the server with header Last-Event-ID set to the last ID sent from the server. The server application can use the ID to backfill data lost during the disconnect.

Answer (score 2):

As per specification client must send Last-Event-Id header to tell the server about last event `id` it successfully received. Only when events are send **with** `id` field with empty value (different from just sending data and ommiting `id` completely) Last-Event-Id resets on client side (you can think of this as block transactions).

See section 5 Processing Model in https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-eventsource-20090421/

> If the event source's last event ID string is not the empty string, then a Last-Event-Id HTTP header must be included with the request, whose value is the value of the event source's last event ID string.

There's good explanation of this later in section 7 Interpreting an Event Stream describing on `test-stream` practical example on how Last-Event-Id sent by client side is affected by value (and presence) of event `id`.